# What is the difference between differential resistance and resistance?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

I came across that $$r_{diff} = \frac{dV}{dI}$$ is the differential resistance. What is the meaning of differential resistance, what does it tell us that conventional resistance doesn't tell us?

Also in this literature I'm reading, the authors choose to perform/read $$ r_{diff} - I$$ plots (differential resistance vs current bias) for a current biased circuit, while I traditionally am used to one taking I-V characteristic readings, so why do they take the first one? And also what does it tell us that I-V characteristic doesn't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's also referred to as **dynamic resistance**.

What you call the differential resistance is of importance when talking about a non-linear resistive element such as a diode as in the trusty 1N4148: -

[image]

Or maybe in the breakdown voltage of a zener diode: -

[image]

So, taking the 1N4148 example, you can see that I/V (or V/I) when the current is (say) 100 mA is significantly different to the slope at a current of 1 mA.

- At 100 mA, the apparent resistance is 1 volt ÷ 100 mA  = 10 ohms
- At 100 mA, the dynamic resistance is **about** 0.2 volts ÷ 10 mA = ~20 ohms
- At 1 mA, the apparent resistance is 0.6 volts ÷ 1 mA  = 600 ohms
- At 1 mA, the dynamic resistance is **about** 0.2 volts ÷ 100 uA = ~2 kohms

As you can see there is a big difference between apparent and dynamic resistance.

For a zener diode, as it starts to conduct, the slope of V/I changes quite a bit as it goes from non-conducting to "fully on". But it's the same basic story of apparent vs dynamic resistance.

> *Also in this literature I'm reading, the authors choose to
>   perform/read \$r_{diff}−I\$ plots (differential resistance vs current bias)
>   for a current biased circuit*

That's because the dynamic resistance varies with applied current (as per the 1N4148 diode).

> *so why do they take the first one? And also what does it tell us that
>   I-V characteristic doesn't?*

Well, the full I-V characteristic does contain the information but sometimes it's helpful if someone has told you what the dynamic resistance is at certain current levels because it saves you working this out.

Comment: And why is it called "dynamic resistance"? What is "dynamic" here?

Comment: Why are your answers so long?

Comment: Because I want things to be understood in depth... and this cannot be done in a few words...

Comment: Why did you use 100uA for last case instead of 1mA?

Comment: @Leoman12 for the same reason I used 10 mA "di" at a standing current of 100 mA. I was trying to find the slope at 1mA and, at 1 mA the slope is circa 200 mV / 100 uA.

Answer (score 4):

Rdiff is valid when one wants to calculate how much in a non-linear circuit (for ex. a transistor amp or diode attenuator) an AC signal gets amplified or attenuated. We call it linearization and it can be used usefully when the AC signal is in the circuit summed to a tens or hundreds times larger DC component. For example transistor has idle collector current say 1 mA and the signal makes the current to swing plusminus 0,1 mA or less.

The calculation of circuit's function with low amplitude AC signals is said "small signal analysis".  For analysis all parts must be modeled with differential values. The calculation of the DC components (= finding the "operating point") are made at first totally separately and the differential (=dynamic) values for parts are derived or measured for those DC values. Your curve Rdiff vs. DC current is a place to find the needed Rdiff for analyses.

Rdiff does not tell anything which isn't included to the full description how a component works, but it's very useful simplification for small signal AC analysis when full description contains mostly non-needed data. You can input to a circuit analysis program easily Rdiff but the full description needs the full model of the used component. Analysis programs calculate in AC analysis the needed differential values from the full model if it's included.

Answer (score -1):

I've seem diodes (emitter-base junctions) used in cellphones as logarithmic signal processors, to handle the Billion-to-One power ratios the handsets experience.

Depending on how the junction is doped, the ideal dynamic-resistance (dV/dI) will change inversely with current.

At 1mA, expect 26 ohms.

At 1microAmp, expect 26,000 ohms

At 1 nanoAmp, expect 26,000,000 ohms (and SLOW response).

The derivative of the Diode equation produces this dV/dT.

Notice I did not give values for 10mA and 100mA. That's because the bulk resistance of the silicon (the "scattering limit") introduces a linear component into the dV/dI and the pure exponential/logarithmic math is no longer available to use with accuracy.